# angular material Dynamic mdTabs and ui-router named view and states

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, tabs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

Currently, I'm working on a project that has requirement of dynamic tabs. I'm using angular material tabs for this purpose and also using ui-router state and named view concept to load the tabs' content dynamically.

For e.g.:

```
<!-- mdTabs -->
  <md-tabs md-autoselect>

    <!-- mdTab -->
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in home.tabs" label="{{tab.title}}" md-on-select="home.selectTab(tab)">

      <md-tab-body>
        <div ui-view="{{tab.viewName}}"></div>
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>

  </md-tabs>
```

Tabs are added like:

```
vm.tabs = [{
      title: 'Tab-A',
      state: 'mainState.tabStateA',
      viewName: 'tabA'
   }, {
     title: 'Tab-B',
     state: 'mainState.tabStateB',
     viewName: 'tabB'
   }];
```

You can take a look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/JEQjaY?editors=1010) for the example implementation.

Background:
Whenever I change the tabs, I'm changing the state and loading the content. This state can further have other n-levels of nested states that can also be loaded dynamically; The tabs can be added or removed dynamically.

Problem: My application can have theoretically unlimited tabs and the problem is that whenever I switch the tabs all the content are loaded again and again which deteriorates the UX as the tabs could be in any of the possible state(UI can change based on the nested level of content).

Question: Can we do something like, as a tab is loaded once it should be cached and so whenever we go back to that same state it should not load again. And, if in the future the tab should be loaded again, we can provide some logic to do this also. I know that somebody must have had similar kind of problem and just out of curiosity I'm posting this question.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @MikeFeltman I did and I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more research and found out that there is `ui-router-extras` which provides some extra support like `StickyStates` aka `ParallelStates`, `Deep State Redirect`, etc. For more info take a look at [ui-router extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home).

For me, it was a dead end as the above-mentioned library support is present for `angular-ui-router ~0.2.8` and I'm currently using the next version of `angular-ui-router` i.e. `1.0.0-rc.1`. So, I contacted the dev(a huge shout-out to [Chris Thielen](https://github.com/christopherthielen)) and got the update that the `Sticky States` for `ui-router rc-1.0.0` implementation is complete. For more info look at the [update](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/336#issuecomment-281370718).

So basically, I'm answering my own question. And the answer is to use `ui-router-extras` if you are on older version of `ui-router` or use `ui-router 1.0.0-rc.1` along with [Sticky States](https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states).

Note: I haven't tested the above-mentioned library, but by looking at the docs I'm pretty sure that in future I'll definitely use this for the above-mentioned problem/question.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar issue but was able to solve it with ui-router 0.4.2. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773277/md-tabs-with-angular-ui-router-not-rendering-grandchildren/42792424#42792424