# md-tabs with angular ui-router not rendering grandchildren

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using Angular 1.6.2 with Angular Material 1.3 and making fairly heavy use of components. I have an outer "appComponent" that wraps the rest of the app and provides a header toolbar with navigation, a footer and then my top-level app components load within a ui-view inside the app component.

One of my components is a customer maintenance page that has a list in a tab on tab 1 and then customer specific details on tab 2.

tab 2 loads another template via ng-include that includes several tabs. A few of those tabs contain child data and I want to lazy load them, so I create states for them like this:

```
 .state('customers', {
                url: "/customers",
                templateUrl: "components/customer/index.html",
                role: "customers",
                resolve: { authenticate: authenticate }
            })
            .state('customers.customer', {
                url: "/{customerId}",
                templateUrl: "components/customer/index.html",
                role: "customers - edit",
                view: "customerdetail",
            })
            .state('customers.customer.acknowledgements', {
                url: "/acknowledgements",
                templateUrl: "components/customer/customerAcknowledgements.html",
                view: "customeracknowledgements",
                onEnter: function() {
                    debugger
                }
            })
            .state('customers.customer.importinstructions', {
                url: "/importinstructions",
                templateUrl: "components/customer/customerImportInstructions.html",
                role: "customers - edit",
                view: "customerImportInstructions",
            })
            .state('customers.customer.orderhistory', {
                url: "/orderhistory",
                templateUrl: "components/customer/customerOrderHistory.html",
                // parent resolve is inherited. Not implementing
                view: "customerOrderHistory",
            })
```

The html inlcudes ui-view with the name argument for each view like so:

```
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height class="md-primary" md-no-select-click md-selected="selectedTab">
            <md-tab label="General Info">
                <!-- content removed for the sake of brevity -->
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label><span ui-sref="customers.customer.acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</span></md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ui-view name="customeracknowledgements"></div>
                    <!--<div ui-view></div>-->
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab layout-fill ui-sref="customers.customer.importinstructions" label="Import Instructions" md-on-select="$ctrl.selectTab('customers.customer.importinstructions')">
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ui-view name="customerImportInstructions"></div>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Order History" ui-sref="customers.customer.orderhistory" md-on-select="$ctrl.selectTab('customers.customer.orderhistory')">
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ui-view=n ame "customerOrderHistory">
                    </div>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
```

I have tried a wide variety of things. I know that the states are being navigated too because I've had the onEnter function used on the customeracknowledgements state on each state and it fires for each one. Also if I watch the network tab in the Chrome developer tools an XHR call is made to retrieve each template when I navigate to the containing tab, but nothing is display on any of the tabs.

I've googled the *#%! out of this, read and tried everything I can find, but nothing has helped. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing the view syntax like this:

```
            .state('customers.customer.acknowledgements', {
                url: "/acknowledgements",
                role: "customers - edit",
                views: { "customeracknowledgements": 
                    { templateUrl: "components/customer/customerAcknowledgements.html" } },
            })
```

and the least verbose way to get the templates to load within the tab bodies and keep all of the animation effects appears to be:

```
            <md-tab label="Acknowledgements" ui-sref="customers.customer.acknowledgements">
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ui-view name="customeracknowledgements"></div>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
```